# storing logs/error message on C programming

Tags: c, linux, error-handling, posix, stderr

When an error occurs, I would like my C code to store the error before exiting the program. Is it advised to store the `stderr` to a file (e.g., /home/logs.txt) or would it be advised to use a different method to keep the logs/error report (considering the programming environment is `Linux`). E.g., for the code below, how I could apply the method to store the logs/error message on `/home/log.txt` or `/home/log`

```
FILE *fp1;
fp1 = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export","w"); 
if(fp1 == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "errno:%s - opening GPIO136 failed - line 739\n ", strerror(errno));
    close(fp1);
    exit(1);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The call to `close()` is wrong, as it's meant for file descriptors not for file handles. You should have reveived a compiler warning/error here, as you pass a pointer to where an integer is expected. However calling `fclose()` would be redundant, as the file had not been opened, which is indicated by `fp1` being `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you alk, I will fix it on my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `stderr` is always used to print out all your error message, so, you can redirect output to a specific file.

```
$ program 2>~/logs.txt
```

For a better logging tool, you can use:

- [`syslog`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) standard function.
- [`log4c`](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: `syslog` is *not* a system call (it is not in section 2 of the `man` pages) but a standard library function. I recommend using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the error, stderr is probably not a good choice because you'll need to pipe stderr to a file every time you run the program.

If you want to write to /home/log.txt, open a FILE pointer to it and write with fprintf the same way you tried to open /sys/class/gpio/export and write to that instead of stderr. Also be sure to open the log file with append mode.

```
FILE *fp1;
fp1 = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export","w"); 
if(fp1 == NULL){
   FILE *fpErr = fopen("/home/log.txt", "a");
   if(fpErr != NULL)
      fprintf(fpErr, "errno:%s - opening GPIO136 failed - line 739\n ", strerror(errno));
   close(fpErr);
   close(fp1);
   exit(1);
}
```